GCP Compute Engine vTPM: DA lockout mode
After restarting the compute engine vm many times, I get this error:
"Failed to fetch and write OIDC token: failed to retrieve attestation service token: failed to attest: failed to quote: warning code 0x21 : authorizations for objects subject to DA protection are not allowed at this time because the TPM is in DA lockout mode"
How can I get around TPM issues? I want to be able to restart my vm as many times as I want.

I do not know the answer but that error means your VM has been attacked/breached. Ubuntu has documentation for how to solve that error but I have not tested those methods in Google Cloud. Are there additional messages displayed with the error message in your question? Edit your post with more details such as OS, complete error details, etc.
